# Possible leftover bits of Windows?

Tags: system-installation, windows

I know that a fresh Ubuntu install can wipe Windows files completely.

But I've heard that Windows writes random hidden data everywhere without your permission. Can there be remains of Windows after a clean install of Ubuntu that can be potentially used by *malicious software* against your data or passwords?

I had a nasty malware attack recently and left Windows for good, but the software service installed Windows again. So will a fresh Ubuntu install by me over Windows wipe it for good?

Comment: I believe Gparted/ubiquity doesn't do a full format-- just a partial format. If you wanna do a full format you have to wait a REALLY LONG TIME. But yeah you'll still have bits and pieces of the Windows OS left, but they will be completely inaccessible after ubiquity's partial format.

Comment: Can you define your question a little more concisely? I'd try at least splitting it into a few paragraphs, but I might just split around the sentences...  Disappointed to hear you sent your drive for erasing, and got an unwanted "free" windows, hopefully it didn't cost much $, or asking for a refund might be an idea. Extra fun: If you had a flash/SSD drive there could be a few sectors that get remapped & are never able to be normally overwritten (or normally read) again. And it's past halloween, but have you considered [firmware malware](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=firmware+malware)? Spooky!

Answer (score 10):

Unless you have some type of [malware in your computer or drive's firmware](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=firmware+malware), then overwriting the drive should completely obliterate any trace of Windows. As Android Dev's answer says, `dd` can do that, or `gnome-disk-utility`/Disks has a GUI and also a "Format - overwrite with zeros" option too, using a progress bar.

But ***overwriting really isn't necessary***, just plain formatting the existing drive's partitions will do it, Windows and its programs can't run from a few leftover sectors of data on a drive, and eventually they'll be overwritten with new data anyway. It takes some effort to get Windows programs to run in Linux at all, only a few can, and any data on a drive that's unallocated (marked as "free space") would be impossible to run normally.

`gparted` can create a new partition table and partitions as well as format them, and it's a GUI program that's [on the basic Ubuntu ISOs](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10/ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.manifest). I believe the "Device" menu has the "create a new MBR/GPT" option, and you can do a lot by clicking/right-clicking on things too.  Writing a new partition table (MBR/GPT) and making new partitions and formatting them is probably overkill, but possible too.

But basically just the Ubuntu installer's option to "Erase the disk and install Ubuntu" or "Replace Windows with Ubuntu" is exactly what you want, it will get rid of Windows. Just like in your example image:

[image]
If windows is already gone.

[image]
If windows is still there.

---

Obviously, if there's any data you care about on the drive, make a backup of it first.

Comment: gparted/parted does nondestructive formatting. The data is still there and recoverable.

Comment: @ravery *"Doesn't matter, still counts"*. The goal isn't to make file recovery impossible, it's to get rid of windows, and windows can't magically run from leftover file fragments in a fresh Ubuntu system. (I didn't actually say gparted could wipe data, but I've clarified a little anyway)

Comment: thank you, that does make it clearer that the discussion has switch from overwriting the drive.

Answer (score 2):

First off, welcome to the amazing world of Linux and open source!

---

The best way to wipe your HDD for good is to write zeros to every sector with `dd` from a live USB/DVD session. Here's the command you'll want:

**Note: replace 'x' with the block device of your HDD**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4M
```

**WARNING: the above command will permanently burn any and all data on the HDD with no hope of recovery**

Also be aware that the above command will take several hours to complete.

Comment: There's also  *"Sending a USR1 signal to a running 'dd' process makes it print I/O statistics to standard error and then resume copying."* trick, with a little math could guess at the time remaining. I'm sure there's programs that can give an "estimated time" for dd too

Comment: For an SSD, prefer using a SATA secure-erase command.  On many SSDs, that will make it re-initialize its firmware mapping table without actually putting in the wear of all those flash writes of zeroes.  (Some SSDs do internal compression, so writing zeros will go fast, but some don't, and IDK if they check for all-zeros as a special case.)

Comment: This is not an ideal way to wipe a disk -- it ignores hidden sectors, is very demanding for the disk, and does a wipe only at the block level, not the hardware level. A better alternative is to use [Secure Erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase). Also, there's no reason to use `dd`, just use `cat` and your shell, which sets sensible block sizes automatically.

Comment: @ChrisDown from what I've read motherboard SATA controller support for the ATA Secure Erase command is quite spotty

Comment: @AndroidDev You must be reading old articles then -- I don't think any computer from 2012+ wouldn't support this :-)

Comment: @ChrisDown well I haven't looked at it for years so it's very possible things have changed :)

Answer (score 0):

When partitions or files are deleted, they aren't actually erased from the disk. They are just erased from the partition or files tables. The data is still there until it is overwritten by another file. This is why undelete software works.

There is software for overwriting free space to completely delete files. As mentioned by Android Dev `dd` is a good command for wiping entire partitions or drives. Note: dd does not output progress, just be patient and wait for it to finish. It will tell you when it is done. My guestemate is about 1 hour for every 100 GB.

After you have installed Ubuntu, `fileshredder` is a good program for overwriting free space in a file system.